# Filter and Map on Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, higher-order-functions

```js
    let team = [
    {'name' : 'Bob Jones', 'Info': {'Height': '6.4', 'Weight': 170}, 'age': 20},
    {'name' : 'John Anderson', 'Info': {'Height': '5.4', 'Weight': 120}, 'age': 23},
    {'name' : 'Tim Hamburger', 'Info': {'Height': '6.1', 'Weight': 180}, 'age': 25},
    {'name' : 'Tom Hamburger', 'Info': {'Height': '6.6', 'Weight': 220}, 'age': 30},
    {'name' : 'Jack Johnson', 'Info': {'Height': '6.0', 'Weight': 190}, 'age': 41},
    {'name' : 'Tommy Tubbs', 'Info': {'Height': '6.1', 'Weight': 180}, 'age': 50},
    ]
    
    let age = (team) => {
      let earlyTwenties = [];
      team.filter((members) => {
        if(members.age >= 20 && members.age <= 25) {
          earlyTwenties.push(members.name)
        }
      });
      return earlyTwenties;
    }
    
    console.log(age(team));//[ 'Bob Jones', 'John Anderson', 'Tim Hamburger' ]
```

I have a function that filters all the team members that are in their early twenties. I need to **return only the team members first names** instead of their full names.

I know I can use a `for-loop` and split each name and then use another for loop to return every other value giving me all the first names, but I'm trying to write better code using HOF.

Any suggestions on how to use map to split the array and return only the first name all in the same function?

Comment: Excuse me, could you precise your desired result? You want to get e.g. `Bob` instead of `Bob Jones`?

Comment: and if so, should they be unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Array#filter` to firstly get every players age that fulfills the condition and then `Array#map` to get just their names using string split.

```js
let team = [
{'name' : 'Bob Jones', 'Info': {'Height': '6.4', 'Weight': 170}, 'age': 20},
{'name' : 'John Anderson', 'Info': {'Height': '5.4', 'Weight': 120}, 'age': 23},
{'name' : 'Tim Hamburger', 'Info': {'Height': '6.1', 'Weight': 180}, 'age': 25},
{'name' : 'Tom Hamburger', 'Info': {'Height': '6.6', 'Weight': 220}, 'age': 30},
{'name' : 'Jack Johnson', 'Info': {'Height': '6.0', 'Weight': 190}, 'age': 41},
{'name' : 'Tommy Tubbs', 'Info': {'Height': '6.1', 'Weight': 180}, 'age': 50},
];

let res = team.filter(v => v.age > 19 && v.age < 26)
              .map(v => v.name.split(" ")[0]);
              
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and for each name, split on white space and return the first element:

```
age(team).map(fullname => fullname.split(" ")[0])
```

---

```js
let team = [
{'name' : 'Bob Jones', 'Info': {'Height': '6.4', 'Weight': 170}, 'age': 20},
{'name' : 'John Anderson', 'Info': {'Height': '5.4', 'Weight': 120}, 'age': 23},
{'name' : 'Tim Hamburger', 'Info': {'Height': '6.1', 'Weight': 180}, 'age': 25},
{'name' : 'Tom Hamburger', 'Info': {'Height': '6.6', 'Weight': 220}, 'age': 30},
{'name' : 'Jack Johnson', 'Info': {'Height': '6.0', 'Weight': 190}, 'age': 41},
{'name' : 'Tommy Tubbs', 'Info': {'Height': '6.1', 'Weight': 180}, 'age': 50},
]

let age = (team) => {
  let earlyTwenties = [];
  team.filter((members) => {
    if(members.age >= 20 && members.age <= 25) {
      earlyTwenties.push(members.name)
    }
  });
  return earlyTwenties;
}

console.log(age(team));

console.log(
  age(team).map(fullname => fullname.split(" ")[0])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get first all objects and then map only the first name of the objects as result set.

```js
let team = [ { name: 'Bob Jones', Info: { Height: '6.4', Weight: 170 }, age: 20 }, { name: 'John Anderson', Info: { Height: '5.4', Weight: 120 }, 'age': 23 }, { name: 'Tim Hamburger', Info: { Height: '6.1', Weight: 180 }, 'age': 25 }, { name: 'Tom Hamburger', Info: { Height: '6.6', Weight: 220 }, age: 30 }, { name: 'Jack Johnson', Info: { Height: '6.0', Weight: 190}, age: 41}, { name: 'Tommy Tubbs', Info: { Height: '6.1', Weight: 180}, age: 50}],
    age = team => team.filter(members => members.age >= 20 && members.age <= 25)
                      .map(members => members.name.split(' ')[0]);

console.log(age(team));//[ 'Bob Jones', 'John Anderson', 'Tim Hamburger' ]
```